# How to set an select value by Javascript when user sets another select value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two select boxes. How is it possible to set via javascript a select value when the user sets another value of a select box?

```
<select id="tasktype" name="task_type">
    <option value="1" selected="selected">Station 1</option>
    <option value="2">Station 2</option>
    <option value="3">Station 3</option>
</select>

<select id="percent" name="percent_complete">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">0%</option>
    <option value="25">25%</option>
    <option value="50">50%</option>
    <option value="75">75%</option>
    <option value="100">100%</option>
</select>
```

So as an example when the user sets tasktype to Station 2, percent will be automatically set to 75.

Comment: Use `change` event. Also post your JS code. http://api.jquery.com/change/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want something like this; on change of the first select, you can test the values and set the second:

```js
$('#tasktype').change(function() {
  if (this.value == 1) {
    $('#percent').val("25");
  } else {
    $('#percent').val("50");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="tasktype" name="task_type">
  <option value="1" selected="selected">Station 1</option>
  <option value="2">Station 2</option>
  <option value="3">Station 3</option>
</select>

<select id="percent" name="percent_complete">
  <option value="0" selected="selected">0%</option>
  <option value="25">25%</option>
  <option value="50">50%</option>
  <option value="75">75%</option>
  <option value="100">100%</option>
</select>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qdga903m/

Answer (score 0):

When Any option is selecte in id tasktype , below function will be called

```
$( "#tasktype" ).change(function() {

$("option[value='25']").attr('selected','selected');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use as below:

```
if($('#tasktype:selected').val() =="2"){
   $("#percent").val("75");
}
```